# How to randomize the order in which lists are displayed in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an HTML list like this:

```
<ul>
<li>This is an item.</li>
<li>This is another item.</li>
<li>This is yet another item.</li>
</ul>
```

How can I have these items displayed in a random order each time the document is loaded?

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: Need some more information. You can always use `ul.magic(random)`, that should do the trick too. Order them can be done in javascript or at serverside though.

Comment: Is `ul.magic(random)` added to the `<ul>`?

Answer (score 1):

Add this javascript:

```
var ul = document.getElementById("list");
for (var i = ul.children.length; i >= 0; i--)
ul.appendChild(ul.children[Math.random() * i | 0]);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xvXJa/)

(This answer was originally provided by [Alexey Lebedev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8338/alexey-lebedev) for this question: [javascript - shuffle HTML list element order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7070054/javascript-shuffle-html-list-element-order/11972692#11972692))

Comment: Atlest give proper attribution

Comment: Yes, i know it's duplicate; I found the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7070054/javascript-shuffle-html-list-element-order)

Answer (score 1):

As it has answer here [javascript - shuffle HTML list element order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7070054/javascript-shuffle-html-list-element-order)

var ul = document.getElementById("item");

for (var i = ul.children.length; i >= 0; i--)
{
    ul.appendChild(ul.children[Math.random() * i | 0]);
}