# How do I shuffle the order of an array in Jekyll?

Tags: ruby, jekyll, liquid

Specifically I'm looking to list an array's contents in random order on a page each time it is generated.

So, given `page.array = [1, 2, 3]` the following:

```
{% for i in page.array %}
  <p>{{ i }}</p>
{% endfor %}

<!-- 
  Yields:
  <p>1</p>
  <p>2</p>
  <p>3</p>
-->
```

How do I randomize that order? (hopefully with syntax somewhat like the following)

```
{% for i in page.array.shuffle %}
  <p>{{ i }}</p>
{% endfor %}

<!--
  Yielding something like this, or a random reordering:
  <p>3</p>
  <p>1</p>
  <p>2</p>
-->
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I managed to achieve this by adding a custom filter via Jekyll's plugin system:

```
# _plugins/shuffle.rb
module Jekyll
  module ShuffleFilter
    def shuffle(array)
      array.shuffle
    end
  end
end

Liquid::Template.register_filter(Jekyll::ShuffleFilter)
```

And using:

```
{% assign shuffled_array = page.array | shuffle %}
{% for i in shuffled_array %}
  <p>{{ i }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I can't figure out for the life of me how to install this plugin. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: @bryan using jekyll v3.6.2 all I had to do was drop the custom filter into a file in `_plugins`, eg. `_plugins/shuffle.rb`

Comment: Is there any way to achieve the same functionality with only the Jekyll plugins found in the GitHub Pages gem? Github-pages does not support custom plugins.

Comment: If you know the length you could use the `sample` filter, but I don't know of any way for a dynamic length of array.

Comment: Thank you! This is my first working custom plugin!

Answer (score 5):

The [currently accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27179386/4463672) uses a custom filter, but this is not possible in some common Jekyll environments, such as GitHub Pages.

An easy workaround that *does* work on GitHub Pages is to use [Jekyll's `sample` filter](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/liquid/filters/) and pass it the `size` of the array. For example, here is a Markdown-formatted Jekyll template that will print the titles of your Jekyll blog posts in random order on each Jekyll build:

```
---
title: Posts in random order
---

{% assign n = site.posts | size %}
{% assign posts = site.posts | sample: n %}
{% for post in posts %}
    * {{ post.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

After trying solutions discussed here, I realized it is better using JS because I can shuffle the list dynamically anytime I want. It is easy to implement. Here is an example:

html

```
<div id="my-list">
  {% for i in page.array %}
    <p>{{ i }}</p>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

js

```
var myList = document.querySelector('#my-list');
for (var i = myList.children.length; i >= 0; i--) {
    myList.appendChild(myList.children[Math.random() * i | 0]);
}
```

Reference: [javascript - shuffle HTML list element order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7070054/javascript-shuffle-html-list-element-order/11972692#11972692)