# Why is an integer returned when disjunction is used with Math.random()?

Tags: javascript, integer

I use
`Math.random() * 10` to get a number between 0 and 10. However, when I use that with disjunction (|), the returned value becomes an integer even though I do not use such methods as Math.floor().

```
let n = Math.random() * 10;
// n is very likely a decimal number.

let n = Math.random() * 10 | 20;
// n becomes an integer.
```

Comment: What do you expect `| 20` to do ?

Comment: @JohnKugelman, my question came from this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11972692/21023788

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`|` is the [bitwise OR operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_OR) and when applied to numbers, it first converts both operands to [32-bit integers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number#fixed-width_number_conversion).